# Create a table containing pipes on ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I create a table in ipython notebook, how can I escape pipes inside of text.

This is what I have

```
identifier | class name | args | distance function
------------|------------------|-------------------
“euclidean” | EuclideanDistance | | sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
“minkowski” | MinkowskiDistance |p| `sum(|x - y|^p)^(1/p)`
```

It comes out as like below but obviously sum(|x - y|^p)^(1/p) is a formula and all the texts need to stay together...

[image]

Comment: How about using ipy_table?  See http://epmoyer.github.io/ipy_table/

Comment: Oh this is a workaround! But ideally, I would like to do it without any additional library. So that when I distribute my notebook, others don't have a trouble.

Comment: You can put raw HTML in a markdown cell including an HTML table.  Examples of HTML table format are at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the escaped pipe version `&#124;` to display the pipe characters properly when table is rendered for ipython notebook markdown cells.

```
identifier | class name | args | distance function
------------|------------------|-------------------
â€œeuclideanâ€ | EuclideanDistance | | sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
â€œminkowskiâ€ | MinkowskiDistance |p| sum(&#124;x - y&#124;^p)^(1/p)
```

*make sure you get rid of the tick marks.

Outcome in notebook should display as such:

[image: ipython markdown - table containing pipes]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Mr cchi!